# Checking similar names using python or R

Tags: python, r, json, nlp, data-science

I am new to text analytics and json file. I have to find the most accurate names in nested json nodes with names in the keyword.

```
  [  
  {   
    "name": "Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar",  
    "DATE OF BIRTH": "",  
    "others": [  
      {  
        "name": "Sachin Tendulkar",  
        "fixedName": "Sachin Tendulkar",  
        "count": 17  
      },  
      {  
        "name": "Sri ajay Tendulkar",  
        "fixedName": "Sri ajay Tendulkar",  
        "count": 10  
      },  
      {  
        "name": "S R tendulkar",  
        "fixedName": "S R tendulkar",  
        "count": 4  
      },  
      {  
        "name":"/Rahul Dravid",  
        "fixedName": "/Rahul Dravid",  
        "count": 4  
      },  
      {  
        "name": "arjun tendulkar",  
        "fixedName": "arjun tendulkar", 
        "count": 1  
      }  
      ]  
  }  
  ]  
},  
{  
  "name": "Mahendra singh dhoni",  
  "DATE OF BIRTH": "",  
  "others": [  
    {  
      "name": "Yuvaraj singh",  
      "fixedName": "Yuvaraj singh",  
      "count": 62  
    },  
    {  
      "name": "M S Dhoni",  
      "fixedName": "M S Dhoni",  
      "count": 50   
    },  
    {  
      "name": "Dhoni M S",  
      "fixedName": "Dhoni M S",  
      "count": 30  
    },  
    {  
      "name": "M S Dutta",  
      "fixedName": "M S Dutta",  
      "count": 26  
    },]
```

I have to search the name Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar and Mahendra singh dhoni with the names in others node. And print the accurate matched names. How it can be done.

the output I am expecting

```
Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar : S R Tendulkar, Sachin Tendulkar  
Mahendra singh Dhoni: M S Dhoni, Dhoni M S.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {d['name']:[itm['name'] for itm in d.get('others',[])] for d in records}
```

I guess would give you about what you want

Comment: I tried. I am getting only the names. Not the matched names from others node. Is this can be done using fuzzywuzzy or any other libraries available or it should be done manually?

Comment: I dont understand what you are asking .... the structure above should mimic the structure you provided as desired output